# Ajax request (Ajax and ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to send Ajax request to a method, but the request is always null, below is my code.

Ajax request, the request reaches the C# method successfully but always the object is null.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SubmitProduct").click(function () {
        var ProductName = $("#ProductName").val();
        var ProductPrice = $("#ProductPrice").val();
        var Category = $("#Categories").val();
        var Data = { ProductName: ProductName, ProductPricd: ProductPrice, Category: Category };
        //console.log("product name: " + ProductName);
        //console.log("Product Price: " + ProductPrice);
        //console.log("Category : " + Category);
        //console.log("data : " + Data.ProductName);
        //The above log are logging data successfully.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Products/SubmitProduct",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(Data),
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            },
            complete: function () {
        
            }

        });
    });
});
```

The below logs shows the result and it's fine(the parameters have the values as expected).

```
// console.log("product name: " + ProductName);
// console.log("Product Price: " + ProductPrice);
// console.log("Category : " + Category);
// console.log("data : " + Data.ProductName);
```

This is the C# method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task <IActionResult> SubmitProduct([FromBody] Products product)
{
    return Content("OK");
}
```

And this is the `Products` class:

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName ="varchar(25)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Product Name is required..")]
    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Product name must be between 2 and 25 characters...")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="ProductName price is required...")]
    [Range(0.001,1000000.000,ErrorMessage = "Price should be between 0.01 and 1000000.000")]
    [Column(TypeName="decimal(10,3)")]
    public decimal ProductPricd { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Image is required...")]
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile ProductImage { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Image Name is required...")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Image Name must be between 3 and 50")]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    [Required]
    public ProductsCategories Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public ApplicationUsers User { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName ="varchar(3)")]
    public string IsDeleted { get; set; } = "0";
}
```

The request reaches the method successfully, but the object is null, any help?

I tried the below ajax, but the object is null too

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Products/SubmitProduct",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        ProductId: "some-guid-value",
        ProductName: "Product Name",
        ProductPrice: 10.99,
        // Other properties here
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("Error: " + data.status + " - " + data.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify` here?  What happens if you remove that?

Comment: to convert the request to Json, without it I will have errors

Comment: The AJAX operation should already be sending the data as JSON.  What error(s) do you get?

Comment: @David I have error: 415 when I remove it

Comment: I updated my test result below, if it not worked for you, could you please share a screenshot of the post request body in your browser like the first screenshot I shared, so that we could try to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve the title; currently the title is just a bunch of tags. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue in my side.

[image]

I'm afraid it related to the model we used, so I create a test model which worked for me.

[image]

This worked as well.

[image]

Then I tried this model, you can see we got null once again.

[image]

In your code snippet, you had `var Category = $("#Categories").val();` which looks like `Category` is a string, but you defined this property as another model. I'm afraid you have to check all of your values set in ajax request.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> sendReq([FromBody] Products2 product)
    {
        return Content("OK");
    }

public class Products2 {
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(25)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name is required..")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPricd { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    [Required]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class Products {
    [Key]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(25)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name is required..")]
    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Product name must be between 2 and 25 characters...")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ProductName price is required...")]
    [Range(0.001, 1000000.000, ErrorMessage = "Price should be between 0.01 and 1000000.000")]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(10,3)")]
    public decimal ProductPricd { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Image is required...")]
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile ProductImage { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Image Name is required...")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Image Name must be between 3 and 50")]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    [Required]
    public ProductsCategories Category { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    //public ApplicationUsers User { get; set; }


    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(3)")]
    public string IsDeleted { get; set; } = "0";
}
public class ProductsCategories {
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

<div id="sendReq">send requyest</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#sendReq").click(function () {
            var ProductName = "prodName";
            var ProductPrice = 15.2;
            var Category = "Categories";
            var Data = { ProductName: ProductName, ProductPricd: ProductPrice, Category: Category };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Hello/sendReq',
                type: 'post',
                data: JSON.stringify(Data),
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.info(result);
                   
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please use text in addition to, or instead of pictures of text. Try reading your answer without the pictures (or replacing the pictures with the text you've chosen, "enter image description here").

Comment: Yes, it seems like the error in the Model class, but I dont know where is it exactly, thank you